# unsigned char* to double in c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am copying double value into unsigned char* in the following way.

```
    unsigned char* cmdBody;
    double val = (double)-1;
    std::ostringstream sstream;
    sstream << val;
    std::string valString = sstream.str();

    unsigned int dataSize = valString.size() + 1;
    cmdBody = (unsigned char*)malloc(dataSize);
    memset(cmdBody, 0, dataSize);
    memcpy(cmdBody, (unsigned char*)valString.c_str(), dataSize - 1);
    cmdBody[dataSize - 1] = '\0';
```

From cmdBody I need to convert the value into double type. How to do it?

Comment: `double val = (double)-1;` - I don't think this makes any sense, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @szczurcio it does make sense, although a more c++ish way is `static_cast<double>(-1);`

Comment: @iharob Aww, I looked at it and for some reason thought of subtraction instead of a negative number. My bad.

Comment: @szczurcio you see why style is soooo important.

Comment: @iharob You're joking, right? The only sane way to write that is `double val = -1;`, there's no problem in having the compiler convert the integer `-1` into a `double` all of its own.

Comment: @unwind I am not, but writing `(double)-1` is very confusing, and of course the cast is absolutely suprefluous here, but really `(double)-1`? And I didn't mean it makes sense, just that it's not wrong.

Comment: personally: `double val = -1.0;`

Comment: Is the `unsigned` essential?

Answer (score 4):

C much?

Your solution is very simple if you just use a `std::string`:

```
const auto val = -1.0; // Input double
const auto cmdBody = std::to_string(val); // Convert double to a std::string
const auto foo = std::stod(cmdBody); // Convert std::string to a double
```

It's important to note that there is no need to allocate, `memcopy`, or null-terminate when constructing a `std::string`. Which vastly simplifies your code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::stod`, something like this:

```
#include <string>
double d = std::stod(cmdBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::istringstream istream(std::string("3.14"));
double d;
istream >> d;
if (!istream.fail())
{
// convertion ok
}
```

Comment: Please add description for your answer.